# Htaccess setup for single-page-application

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, single-page-application

I'm struggling with my htaccess file for a new website. I tried searching the forum, but noone has a working solution I can copy. Here is a description of the setup I need:

- Always "www": "test.com" becomes "www.test.com"
- Always SSL: "http://" becomes "https://"
- Always trailing slash: "test.com/products" becomes "test.com/products/"
- And all non-existing folders point to the
  index.php file (it's a single-page-app structure).

Here's my current htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# www and ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Send all traffic to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

This works in many situations, but there are a few where it doesn't:

- "http://www.test.com/products/" becomes "https://www.test.com/index.php" - but it should just change to SSL and nothing else.
- "http://www.test.com/" becomes "https://www.www.test.com/" (as above, this should just change to "https").

I hope someone can spot the problem here. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have suffixed the last line of each rule group with `[R=301,L]`

- `R=301` means that if the condition is met, redirect the user with a
  301 status code.
- `L` means that if the condition is met, stop here.

Thus you have not just one, but two stop requests once a condition is met.

If you remove both, the script RewriteEngine will continue.